# Twilio Call Error: 20101, Invalid Access Token

Tags: android, twilio, voice

I am facing an error. I want to make a voice call app and I have done everything following there docs. But it showing **Call Error: 20101, Invalid Access Token**

I have an api key using there cli.

my server/.env

```
API_KEY_SID=SK36c7baaad6b9e4700100250ee0db637f
API_SECRET=8jNHpFE6X0yV6QbL1plXY7VkAlsG6c2G
APP_SID=AP5e7f21f5b5036fe7f57b82e9c1bbf009
PUSH_CREDENTIAL_SID=CRxxxx
```

I have get the api key and check it using jwt.io

It showing,

```
{
  "jti": "SK36c7baaad6b9e4700100250ee0db637f-1692784044",
  "grants": {
    "identity": "alice",
    "voice": {
      "incoming": {
        "allow": true
      },
      "outgoing": {
        "application_sid": "AP5e7f21f5b5036fe7f57b82e9c1bbf009"
      }
    }
  },
  "iat": 1692784044,
  "exp": 1692787644,
  "iss": "SK36c7baaad6b9e4700100250ee0db637f",
  "sub": "********"
}
```

where is the problem what i can do now